# EfficientDet-Custom Dataset -StringToNumberOp could not correctly convert string

Tags: python, tensorflow, error-handling, efficientnet

As a beginner, I am trying to train my custom datasets with TensorFlow, but getting the following error when start training:

[image]

here is my command line:

```
python main.py --mode=train_and_eval
--training_file_pattern=tfrecord/train.record
--validation_file_pattern=tfrecord/test.record
--model_name=efficientdet-d0
--model_dir=/tmp/efficientdet-d0-scratch
--backbone_ckpt=efficientnet-b0
--train_batch_size=8
--eval_batch_size=8 --eval_samples=512
--num_examples_per_epoch=5717 --num_epochs=1
--hparams="num_classes=4,moving_average_decay=0"
--use_tpu=False
```

Answer (score 2):

Answered here on github. Its an issue with tfrecord creations. In your tf record creation script, change source_id

```
'image/source_id': dataset_util.bytes_feature(input_image_filename.encode('utf8')),
```

to

```
'image/source_id': dataset_util.bytes_feature('0'.encode('utf8')),
```

You don't need to modify any filenames. Original link below.

https://github.com/google/automl/issues/307#issuecomment-626587210